# Why does the value of the variables in list change in Python?

Tags: python, json, variables

I don't understand this behavior of the Python 2.7.12...

Please verify the code, pasted below:

```
test = [(('AAA_1', 'BBB_1', 'CCC_1'), 1), (('AAA_2', 'BBB_2', 'CCC_2'), 2),(('AAA_3', 'BBB_3', 'CCC_3'), 3), (('AAA_4', 'BBB_4', 'CCC_4'), 4)]
for i, j in enumerate(test):
    for k, l in enumerate(j[0]):
        if k == 0:
            dc['first'] = l
        elif k == 1:
            dc['second'] = l
        elif k == 2:
            dc['third'] = l
        elif k == 3:
            dc['fourth'] = l
    c.append(dc)
    print "/n"
    print "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
    print dc
    print json.dumps(c, indent=1)
    print c

print json.dumps(c, indent=1)
```

Results of the code displayed above are stored in public pastebin: http://pastebin.com/GkrTyseg

What is strange for me:
By appending the list: c I would like to received the list of dictionaries. This dictionaries may represent the each type of AAA,BBB,CCC tuples. I used dictionaries to convert this into json to have easy way to use this data by webservices.

Anyway, I expected to receive the json:

```
 {
  "second": "BBB_1",
  "third": "CCC_1",
  "first": "AAA_1"
 },
 {
  "second": "BBB_2",
  "third": "CCC_2",
  "first": "AAA_2"
 },
 {
  "second": "BBB_3",
  "third": "CCC_3",
  "first": "AAA_3"
 },
 {
  "second": "BBB_4",
  "third": "CCC_4",
  "first": "AAA_4"
 }
```

But actual results are:

```
 {
  "second": "BBB_4",
  "third": "CCC_4",
  "first": "AAA_4"
 },
 {
  "second": "BBB_4",
  "third": "CCC_4",
  "first": "AAA_4"
 },
 {
  "second": "BBB_4",
  "third": "CCC_4",
  "first": "AAA_4"
 },
 {
  "second": "BBB_4",
  "third": "CCC_4",
  "first": "AAA_4"
 }
```

Why previously appended values changes their values to new ones?

The same results I recieived when I used instead of list: c additional dictionary, to get prettier json, than using list. But results were the same...
I tried using (instead of the list: c):

```
main_dc[i+1] = dc
```

How can I prevent to not change the values of the elements of the list or dictionary?

Comment: where did `dc` come from? You keep updating the same dict with different values... overwriting the old ones as you go. I think you need to createa a new `dc` dict in each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should append a copy of the dictionary to the list (which is essentially a new dictionary whose reference is not `dc`), so that further changes to the dictionary are not made on the same object appended previously:

```
c.append(dc.copy())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this resolving my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use deep [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)(although there are other ways). When you don't use deep and use referenced like objects, this will happen! here is your code changed with deep copy and works fine:

```
import copy
import json
test = [(('AAA_1', 'BBB_1', 'CCC_1'), 1), (('AAA_2', 'BBB_2', 'CCC_2'), 2),(('AAA_3', 'BBB_3', 'CCC_3'), 3), (('AAA_4', 'BBB_4', 'CCC_4'), 4)]
c = []
for i, j in enumerate(test):
    dc = copy.deepcopy({}) #or simply dc = {}
    for k, l in enumerate(j[0]):
        if k == 0:
            dc['first'] = l
        elif k == 1:
            dc['second'] = l
        elif k == 2:
            dc['third'] = l
        elif k == 3:
            dc['fourth'] = l
    c.append(dc)
    print "/n"
    print "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
    print dc
    print json.dumps(c, indent=1)
    print c

print json.dumps(c, indent=1)
```

here is a good example for seeing difference of deep copy and shallow copy

```
In [1]: l1 = [1,2,3,4]

In [2]: l2 = l1

In [3]: l3 = copy.deepcopy(l1) #import copy

In [4]: l2[0] = 0

In [5]: l1
Out[5]: [0, 2, 3, 4]

In [6]: l2
Out[6]: [0, 2, 3, 4]

In [7]: l3
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Why would you deepcopy an empty dictionary, when you can simply do `dc = {}`. And even if you needed to copy, `deepcopy` is still not applicable here.

Comment: You are right ;) ! But I just wanted him to learn the concept of copying and referencing!

Comment: Thank you for your help and lesson!
I didn't know that there is something like deepcopy in python! This solution resolves my problem! Now I'm smarter, thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

In your code the definition of `dc` is missing, but I assume that you define it **before** all the loops. That means that you don't generate a new `dc` object in each iteration. Instead, you reuse the first one, overwrite its contents, and append it again and again to `c`. "Append" means here, that four links to the same object are appended to `c`.

You should move the definition of `dc` **inside** the `i, j` loop,  just before entering the `k, l` loop. That creates a new object in each iteration of the `i, j` loop.

```
...
for i, j in enumerate(test):
    dc = {}
    for k, l in enumerate(j[0]):
    ...
```

Comment: There was exactly how you wrote. Thank you for help, it resolves my problem!